# Pre-Populating forms in Flask not working

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I am using Flask and HTML to make a form that's already populated, when I have the value set in HTML on Flask when I do request.form.get('name') it just returns blank.

```
@main.route('/update/user', methods=['POST'])
def update_ban():
    name = request.form.get('name')
    print(name)
    return render_template('index.html') #Temp until finished system
```

```
 <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Example: parker02311" value="test" disabled>
```

I am not sure why its just returning None instead of test, any help appreciated.

Comment: Your field is `disabled`.

Comment: That's not the issue, its disabled for a reason there's a ton more that arent which are also returning nones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out there was two issues, anyone in the future who needs help this is the fix:
Make sure no fields are disabled
In your API make sure the update is made properly